# How can I generate POSIX values for yesterday and today at midnight in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, posix

I've been struggling to determine how I can generate a POSIX (UNIX) time value for today and yesterday (midnight) via Python. I created this code, but keep stumbling with how to convert them to a POSIX value:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
today_string = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
yesterday_string = (datetime.now() - timedelta(0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

today = datetime.strptime(today_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
yesterday = datetime.strptime(yesterday_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print time.mktime(today).timetuple()
```

This code yields an exception:

```
TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime
```

At this point, I'm at my wits end. Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: Err, you are making this overcomplex. Give me a minute…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply the `timetuple()` method to the `today` object, not to the result of `time.mktime(today)`:

```
>>> time.mktime(today.timetuple())
1345845600.0
```

By the way, I'm wrong or `yesterday` will be equal to `today` in your code?

**edit:**
To obtain the POSIX time for today you can simply do:

```
time.mktime(datetime.date.today().timetuple())
```

Answer (score 1):

@Bakuriu is right here. But you are making this overcomplex.

Take a look at this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import time

today = date.today()
today_unix = time.mktime(today.timetuple())

yesterday = today - timedelta(1)
yesterday_unix = time.mktime(yesterday.timetuple())
```

Since the `date` object doesn't hold time, it resets it to the midnight.

You could also replace the last part with:

```
yesterday_unix = today_unix - 86400
```

but note that it wouldn't work correctly across daylight saving time switches (i.e. you'll end up with 1 AM or 23 PM).

Comment: Ops, I just edited my answer because I did not see this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a unix timestamp from a datetime object as a string and as a float:

```
datetime.now().strftime('%s')
'1345884732'

time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
1345884732.0
```

Comment: This is not the time he is looking for…

Comment: Is it not? The gist of his question is about converting datetimes to unix timestamps. Downvote all you want, but I simply directed the man to  the right library functions.

Comment: You said *it's much simpler than that*. So you seem to be suggesting a simpler solution to his problem (which is a solution not to his problem at all).

Comment: When you put it that way, yes, it is misleading. Editing for clarity.