# Find HTML between two variables using Python regex

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, html-parsing

New to Python

Trying to scrape some desired info from a webpage.  First thing I would like to get is all HTML between today and yesterday's dates.  Here is what I have so far

```
import datetime
import urllib
import re

t = datetime.date.today()
t1 = t.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
y = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
y1 = y.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://www.blu-ray.com/itunes/movies.php?show=newreleases")
htmltext = htmlfile.read()

block1 = re.search(t1 + r'(.*)' + re.escape(y1), htmltext)
print block1
```

From what I can tell (and I'm probably wrong), my regex should grab what I want it to, so that I can then start pulling out info from today's date only.  But it returns 'None'.

I'm sure that it's just my limited understanding as I am new to this but any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is that `.*` doesn't match line breaks. But you really should use a HTML parser, like alecxe said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use regular expression for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), use an **HTML Parser**, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

This would be a lot of code, but the idea is to iterate over all `h3` elements that contain the date in the specified format (`%B %d, %Y`), then get all [next `table` tags](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) until we hit an another `h3` tag or an end:

```
from datetime import datetime
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = urllib.urlopen("http://www.blu-ray.com/itunes/movies.php?show=newreleases")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

def is_date(d):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(d, '%B %d, %Y')
        return True
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return False

for date in soup.find_all('h3', text=is_date):
    print date.text

    for element in date.find_next_siblings(['h3', 'table']):
        if element.name == 'h3':
            break

        print element.a.get('title')
    print "----"
```

Prints:

```
December 17, 2014
App (2013)
----
December 16, 2014
The Equalizer (2014)
Annabelle (2014)
A Walk Among the Tombstones (2014)
The Guest (2014)
Men, Women & Children (2014)
At the Devil's Door (2014)
The Canal (2014)
The Bitter Tears of Petra von Kant (1972)
Avatar (2009)
Atlas Shrugged Part III: Who Is John Galt? (2014)
Expelled (2014)
Level Five (1997)
The Device (2014)
Two-Bit Waltz (2014)
The Devil's Hand (2014)
----
December 15, 2014
Star Trek: The Next Generation, Season 6 (1992-1993)
Ristorante Paradiso, Season 1 (2009)
A Certain Magical Index II, Season 2, Pt. 2 (2011)
Cowboy Bebop, The Complete Series (1998-1999)
```

Feel free to ask additional questions about the posted code - would be glad to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was throwing an error on `t.strftime("%B %d, %Y")`.

The correct format for the line is `t1 = strftime("%B %d, %Y", t)`

I was also getting: TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime

From this error, you can search for many solutions. I don't know which version of Python you're using, but the solutions use the entire time, not just the date. So you probably need to get the time and subtract a day.

See here: [Extract time from datetime and determine if time (not date) falls within range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138744/extract-time-from-datetime-and-determine-if-time-not-date-falls-within-range)

And here: [How can I generate POSIX values for yesterday and today at midnight in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119299/how-can-i-generate-posix-values-for-yesterday-and-today-at-midnight-in-python)